# What is the difference between "yell" and "scream"?

Tags: word-usage, word-difference, word-meaning

I am having some problems to differentiate between "yell" and "scream".

From what I understand ([and read](http://www.english-test.net/forum/ftopic44155.html)), when somebody *screams* he/she is shouting in a loud way. Then, *yelling* is the same, only that it has the connotation of shouting out of control.

Am I right? Is there any piece of context I am missing?

Comment: In my mind, *scream* refers mostly to the sound/noise, while *yell* is directed. Often you *yell* at someone. Also *yell* is more verbal. But the difference is not so much. Some context or examples would be helpful.

Comment: @user3169 this comes from [a question](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/24810/why-is-my-daughter-shouting-so-much#comment50243_24810) I asked in another [SE] site. I want to express the sound an infant produces when he just shouts randomly. It is something without a direction, because can be done when he is alone.

Comment: I can't think of a context where a baby "yells".

Comment: @user3169 that's the point here. Since I was asked to distinguish between "yell" and "scream", I wondered what the difference is.

Comment: I'd prefer *'scream'* when the things are horrific! ;P

Comment: to yell contains the additional information that it is a very high-pitched sound. It you step on the tail of a little dog it yells.

Comment: @rogermue - ?!  I would think of it in exactly the opposite way!  To me, *scream* implies a higher pitch than *yell*.

Comment: @rogermue, maybe you are thinking of **yelp**? http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/yelp

Answer (score 4):

[scream](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/scream) - to cry or say something loudly and usually on a high note, especially because of strong emotions such as fear, excitement, or anger

[yell](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/yell) - to shout something or make a loud noise, usually when you are angry, in pain, or excited

Both definitions are very similar, as is the generally understood meaning.

Some people might have a preference about which word to use in a particular situation, but that would be a personal preference rather than a difference in generally understood meaning.

For example, I would probably use **scream** rather than **yell** about something non-verbal- for example the noise people make when they are on a rollercoaster ride at the fairground.

Comment: Both definitions are quite similar, so I am still missing the point here. What makes the difference here: the height? whether it is a controlled emotion or not?

Comment: @fedorqui, the point is that the generally understood meanings are every similar.

Comment: I would use yell and not scream if I'm talking loudly because I want to be heard in a noisy environment or from far away. To me screaming is either an indication of very strong emotion, or it is high pitched yelling (probably because voices tend to go up in pitch when people are excited). For example, "The children screamed with glee." or "She yelled 'I'll be right there!' as she started walking across the construction site." If she screamed "I'll be right there!" I would think she was panicked or angry or frustrated instead of just trying to be heard.

Comment: @ColleenV, exactly- we all have personal preferences but they are not universal. I would use yell for anger, scream for fear, shout for raising the voice in order to be heard.

Answer (score 1):

They can be used interchangeablly in many situations, like *big* and *large*. 
For example, screaming, yelling, hollering, shouting, and crying can all refer to *words* uttered at a high volume.

> "You dirty SOB, you're gonna regret the day you were born!"  screamed/yelled/shouted/hollered/cried  Bill.

However, there can be a difference between screaming and yelling.

**[This is screaming](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=BFqHyCoypfM)**.  There are no words to *this kind* of screaming, just an expression of horror. Compare the noise to a crying baby. This is not usually described as yelling. Because when you yell, shout, holler, *etc* you are usually producing actual words.

Note the video **[Top Ten Movie Yells](https://youtu.be/_GCO4_fghMw)** includes "yells only in which words are spoken,"  thus differentiating yells from screams (the famous shower scene in *Psycho* is a scream, not a yell).

Both 'scream' and 'cry' can refer to times when someone makes loud vocal noises that do not include actual words. If it is a baby we usually use the word *cry*. If it is someone who can talk, we can use either *cry* or *scream*.

When words are included, it can also be called a yell, holler, shout.

---

Particular contexts and historical usages make it difficult to cover all cases.   For example, a [battle cry](http://www.artofmanliness.com/2015/06/08/battle-cries/)  may be called a *yell* even though it contains no words  as such. The battle cry of the South, the [Rebel Yell](https://youtu.be/s6jSqt39vFM?t=1m25s),  is an example.

Answer (score 1):

The differences in connotation vary by location, but generally "yelling" is less loud and, more importantly, less intense. If one is screaming, it is at the top of their voice, sometimes incoherent, and sometimes accompanied by physical violence.